# The database backend does not accept 0 as a value for AutoField

Tags: django

Когда я пытаюсь сохранить созданный `promo`, вылезает такая ошибка:

> The database backend does not accept 0 as a value for AutoField.

Моя модель:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _, pgettext_lazy
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
import string
import random
from catalog.models import Category
from mptt.forms import TreeNodeChoiceField
from mptt.models import TreeOneToOneField


def id_generator(size=16, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))


class Promo(models.Model):
    promo = models.CharField(_('promo'), max_length=50, blank=False, default=id_generator)
    discount = models.DecimalField(_('Discount %'), max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, default=0, blank=True)
    discount_money = models.DecimalField(_('Discount (rub)'), max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, default=0, blank=True)
    order_id = models.CharField(_('order number'), max_length=50, blank=True, default=0)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    part_number = models.CharField(_('part number'), max_length=255, blank=True)
    category = TreeOneToOneField(Category, verbose_name=_('category'), blank=True, default=0)
    date_end = models.DateTimeField(_('Date end'), default=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('promo')
        verbose_name_plural = _('promo')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.promo

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, discount_money):
        promo = cls(discount_money=discount_money)
        promo.save()

        return promo
```

В чем причина этой ошибки?

---

```
def subscribe(self, email):
    self.model_class.objects.get_or_create(
        email=email,
    )
    self.create_promo()

@staticmethod
def create_promo():
    promo = Promo.create(config.SUBSCRIPTION_DISCOUNT)
    print promo
```

Comment: Какая база данных? Какой уходит запрос? Возможно, проблема в TreeOneToOneField. Посмотрите, нет ли в этом поле в базе значений "0".

Comment: @Chikiro у меня ещё нет записей в таблице Promo. Может попробовать удалить оттуда `default`? Все равно же там `blank=true`.

Comment: show create table покажите, ошибка связана с полем date_end? mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо [@FeroxTL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176345/feroxtl) за [наводку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/538110/192100)

Проблема была в этой строке:

```
category = TreeOneToOneField(Category, verbose_name=_('category'), blank=True, default=0)
```

Тут при создании по умолчанию передавалась категория `0`, которой в моей БД не было. Простое удаление `default=0` помогло исправить проблему.

Заодно переписал `create`. Вот, что получилось:

```
class PromoManager(models.Manager):
    def create_promo_code(self, discount_money):
        promo = self.create(discount_money=discount_money)

        return promo


class Promo(models.Model):
    promo = models.CharField(_('promo'), max_length=50, blank=False, default=id_generator, primary_key=True)
    discount = models.DecimalField(_('Discount %'), max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, default=0, blank=True)
    discount_money = models.DecimalField(_('Discount (rub)'), max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, default=0, blank=True)
    order_id = models.CharField(_('order number'), max_length=50, blank=True, default=0)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    part_number = models.CharField(_('part number'), max_length=255, blank=True)
    category = TreeOneToOneField(Category, verbose_name=_('category'), blank=True)
    date_end = models.DateTimeField(_('Date end'), default=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('promo')
        verbose_name_plural = _('promo')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.promo

    objects = PromoManager()
```

Answer (score 1):

[Autofield](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#autofield) обычно генерируется автоматически. Причиной ошибки может быть то, что вы где-то  передаёте id=0 при создании экземпляра модели. Подозрительных мест в предоставленном вами коде более нет.

- Во-первых, покажите код, который создаёт экземпляр модели - views.py или из консоли, если вручную
- create лучше вынести в собственный [Manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers), а не лепить его как classmethod